# How to pass 2 JavaScript variables through a url?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I am trying to have 2 variable values passed in a url, which url will be redirected after. How can I insert them in a JavaScript string?

I have:

```
var a = document.getElementById("username_a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("username_b").value;
```

and want something like:   `var string_url = "http://www.example.com/?{a}blabla={b}"` and then redirect somehow.

In PHP I would go with that code for example: `<iframe src="http://www.example.com?query=<?php echo $the_variable;?>">`

Answer (score 7):

You can add strings in JavaScript, `"a" + "b" == "ab"` evaluates to `true`.

So what you want is probably `var string_url = "http://www.example.com/?" + a + "&blabla=" + b;`

But you should ever escape vars especially if they come from `input`s, so try

```js
a = encodeURIComponent(a);
b = encodeURIComponent(b);
```

And then

```js
var string_url = "http://www.example.com/?" + a + "&blabla=" + b;
```

To redirect you can use `window.location`:

```js
window.location = string_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ampersand to split vars

```
var string_url = "http://www.example.com/?" + "username_a=" + a + "&username_b=" + `b
```

Could be made more sopisticated, but that in essence is what you need

Comment: This is taking user input. The data **needs** escaping or it will break.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't do string interpolation. You have to concatenate the values.

```
var uri = "http://example.com/?" + encodeUriComponent(name_of_first_variable) + "=" + encodeUriComponent(value_of_first_variable) + '&' + encodeUriComponent(name_of_second_variable) + "=" + encodeUriComponent(value_of_second_variable);
location.href = uri;
```